# Mongo Mapper rails querying join (or attr_accessor) father and children object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have two models for example:

```
father
 key Name, String
 many :childrens



children
 key type, String
 belongs_to :father
```

I want to query all the fathers that has a children with a particular type for example type == "home"

Which is the more efficient way to do such a task (I'm using mongo mapper)?

I would like to use a query and not a select function on the father collection.

Comment: Mongo doesn't support joins, so you can't do this in one shot.

Comment: I know that's why I was looking the most efficient methods. I mean I know that i can do stuff like Father.chilldrens.select {|item| item.type == "home"} but I want just to look for a more efficient way to do so.

Comment: You would have to do something like finding all children that have type == home, map out all the father_ids, uniq them, and then find all Father instances matching any of those IDs.

Comment: @ChrisHeald can you do an example? Do you think that this is the most efficient way?